# How to use match any number of digits with Java match?

Tags: java, regex, string, match

I am using the Java match function, and I using the * syntax.

```
*-a*
```

Should match `<anything>-a<any digit, from 1 to 7 characters>`
but if I put the `*` it will match any characters, not only numbers.

Comment: Can you show the code you are executing, the desired input and the desired output, please?

Comment: The documentation is there: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: It is using the AntPathMatcher

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `\d` regex element:

```
if (myString.matches(".*-a\\d{1,7}")) {
    // Do something...
}
```